# Is $\sin(nx)$ equicontinuous on $[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, equicontinuity

Consider $f_n=\sin(nx),\,x\in[0,1]$. In order to show that this is not an equicontinuous family, take $x=0,y=\frac{1}{N}$ where $N \in \mathbb{N}$ can be arbitrarily large, so $\forall \, \delta>0 \rightarrow y<\delta$.

Now, if we consider $|f_N(x)-f_N(y)|=|\sin(N\frac{1}{N})|=|\sin(1)|$, hence there exists $\varepsilon_0 > 0$ such that $\forall \, \delta>0,\, \exists\, x=0,\, y=\frac{1}{N},\, N \in \mathbb{N} \,  \text{ such that } |x-y|=y<\delta, \, \text{ but } |f_N(x)-f_N(y)| \geq \varepsilon_0$

Is there anything not right with that logic?

Comment: I think it is perfect. Only for more clarity, I'd specify that $\epsilon_0=\sin 1$. You can also take $y=\pi/(2N)$ (assuming $N\ge 2$) if you prefer a number more... "normal".

Comment: I think this is problematic because it needs to be for all $x,y \in [0,1]$ and here you have fixed x.

Comment: @AndyDufresne This solution is correct. For every $\delta$ one must find $x,y\in [0,1]$ and $N\in\mathbb N$.