# Proving a sequence of functions is not equicontinuous

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification, sequence-of-function, equicontinuity

While studying for my **Real Analysis** exam, i tried to solve the following problem:

**Problem:**

Prove that the family $\{\sin n x, n=1,2,3 \ldots\}$ is not equicontinuous at any point $x_{0}$ in $[0,1]$.

**Relevant definitions:**

**->** Given $x_{0} \in X$, we will say that the set $E$ is equicontinuous at $x_{0}$ when, given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that:

$$
\forall x \in X,\left|x-x_{0}\right|<\delta \Rightarrow\left|f(x)-f\left(x_{0}\right)\right|<\varepsilon $$

for any $f \in E$

**->** A set $E$ of functions $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is called equicontinuous when the set $E$ is equicontinuous at each $x_{0} \in X .$

**Attempt:**

Consider $x_{0}$ in $[0,1]$ fixed and take $\epsilon = 1$. Given any $\delta > 0$ we can always obtain $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that:

$$\frac{1}{n} < \delta$$

Then, the point $x = x_{0} + \frac{1}{n}$ is such that: $$
\left|x-x_{0}\right|=\frac{1}{n}<\delta
$$

**However**,
$$
\left|f_{n}(x)-f_{n}\left(x_{0}\right)\right|= \left|\sin(nx) - sin(n x_{0})\right| \leq$$

$$|sin(nx)| + |sin(n x_{0})| \leq 1 + 1 = 2$$

So, in the worst case scenario, $$\left|f_{n}(x)-f_{n}\left(x_{0}\right)\right| = 2 > 1 = \epsilon$$

**Questions?**

1. Is the proof correct? I have seen some proofs which are a bit different and so i got a little suspicious regarding my attempt.
2. Is it well written? I am trying to become better each day at writing proofs.

[The sequence of functions $f_n = \sin{nx}$ is not uniformly equicontinuous on any compact interval.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3431416/the-sequence-of-functions-f-n-sinnx-is-not-uniformly-equicontinuous-on-an)

[Is $\sin(nx)$ equicontinuous on $[0,1]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2042233/is-sinnx-equicontinuous-on-0-1)

Thanks in advance, Lucas

Comment: It is not correct. You showed the absolute value is at most $2$; you can not assume, from this alone, that it takes the value $2$.

Comment: But, you could show that since the periods of the $f_n$ get small, that your absolute value can be made greater than $1$.

Comment: I agree i cant assume the absolute value is exactly 2. However, since it is at most 2, any value of epsilon less than that should work (or not?)

Comment: I think so, but you need to explain why. The inequality does not say *there are* values of $x$ that make it big.

Comment: Select $n$ so that the period of $f_n$ is less than $\delta$. Then in the interval $[x_0, x_0+\delta]$, $f_n$ takes both the values $1$ and $-1$. From this it follows that your absolute value can be made greater than $1$.

Comment: I am convinced that should work. However, i still dont get why my approach wont work. Can you elaborate a little further?

Comment: You wrote essentially this: $| A|\le 2$, so $A=2$, somewhere. Is this true for $A=\sin x$?

Comment: I think it is, since i have used that $|sin(x)| \leq 1$

Comment: If it were some $A \in \mathbb{R}$ without any special property or inequality i could use, i would not have obtained -2 and 2 as bounds

Comment: In a previous comment, I should have said "at least $1$", not "greater than $1$".

Comment: If $x_0=0$, you are saying $|\sin(nx)|=2$.

Comment: True. So are there two problems in the proof? Selecting $x_0$ and the thing regarding the inequality?

Comment: Yes. $ x_0$ is fixed, and your "worst case" does not follow.

Comment: edit: I was supposed to show that equicontinuity does not hold in [0,1]

Comment: Making the choice of $x$ and $x_0$ more explictly should help you think. How can we choose $x$ and $x_0$ so that $|x - x_0| < 1/n$ but $|\sin nx - \sin n x_0| = 2$?